# Intuition behind hexadecimal subtraction result

Tags: arithmetic, binary

By doing  **hexadecimal subtraction** i got

$(BA)_{16}-(AB)_{16}=(F)_{16}$ similarly

$(CB)_{16}-(BC)_{16}=(F)_{16}$

$(DC)_{16}-(CD)_{16}=(F)_{16} $

$(ED)_{16}-(DE)_{16}=(F)_{16}$

$(FE)_{16}-(EF)_{16}=(F)_{16}$

I am interested in knowing, does similar kind of result holds in other bases too  or not and can I expect similar kind of property in other bases?

In gist I just want to know intuition behind this result. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very similar things appear in any base, and with larger differences between the digits:
$$76-67=9,74-47=27=3×9\ (10)$$
$$A9-9A=B,B7-7B=38=4×B\ (12)$$
In general, in base $b$ where $x>y$ are digits,
$$\overline{xy}-\overline{yx}=(x-y)(b-1)$$
as can be easily verified algebraically.

Comment: very nice general result .can you explain why $xy$ complement  not $xy$ in your formula

Comment: @veereshpandey $\overline{xy}$ has a special meaning when talking about digits. It means "the number formed by concatenating the digits $x,y$", and is used to distinguish it from a product.